# PHP Script to Get File From Another Server and Save on My Server

Tags: php, ftp, cron

I have been playing around with a few php scripts trying to first at least get the php file to connect to the ftp on my distributors file and THEN i would like it to save on my file. I was going to save this as a cron to run this script daily. I can't get it to connect to the distributors ftp. Their ftp access is ftp.aphrodite.WEBSITE.net
The exact location of the file is ftp.aphrodite.WEBSITE.net/exporting/xml/products.xml
I can acces it with filezilla and my browser. This is a different language to me. Any  help would be great!

```
<?php
$conn_id = ftp_connect("ftp.aphrodite.WEBSITE.net/exporting/xml/products.xml");
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) {
echo "FTP connection has failed!";
exit;
} else {
echo "Connected";
}

// get the file
$local = fopen("products.xml","w");
$result = ftp_fget($conn_id, $local,"httpdocs/products.xml", FTP_BINARY);

// check upload status
if (!$result) {
echo "FTP download has failed!";
} else {
echo "Downloaded";
}

// close the FTP stream
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

If I do not use the full url to the ftp file I do not get a login when using a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You supplied  a wrong parameter to `ftp_connect()`, this function accept as parameter the hostname, not url.

```
 $conn_id = ftp_connect("ftp.aphrodite.WEBSITE.net");
```

Comment: Warning: ftp_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in  /home/directory/ProductGet.php on line 2

Warning: ftp_login() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/directory/ProductGet.php on line 3
FTP connection has failed!

Comment: Did you change `WEBSITES` with the host name of your ftp server.

Comment: Try to get the IP of this host to see if this server was alive

Comment: when i put the ftp://aphrodite.website.net/exports/xml/products.xml in says it cannot get the ip.... Any way to have php login and just download the file with the exact path to the file? I just need some automation to get the file on a directory on my server.

Comment: got it showing up like this: <?php 
$content = file_get_contents('http://user:password@host.com/file.xml');
?> but how can i get it to save in a folder on my server?